# How to link data from a Firebird database with a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, firebird

I'm used to using SQL Server fairly often as part of my work to produce data for reporting. A new customer has data in both SQL Server and Firebird databases. I've never interacted with Firebird in anyway so this may seem a fairly simple question but what would be the best way to link data between the two systems? I'll need to build a small datamart to hold the linked data eventually as my end goal.

I am aware the customer has Database Workbench installed for the client side of Firebird and I believe this will allow me to use SQL Server syntax on the FB databases but will it allow me to link data between the two and create new views in the SQL Server database with it? Obviously I know I can create a linked server in SQL Server Management Studio but I've had anecdotal advice that this can be difficult to configure potentially and if there's a simpler way then I'd prefer to go that way.

Comment: As far as I know creating a linked server using the Firebird ODBC driver in SQL server is the only viable way, especially if you also need views to combine the data.

Comment: "*I believe this will allow me to use SQL Server syntax on the FB databases*" - no it won't. Firebird does not understand T-SQL

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you just confirm that when you say that I can't use SQL server syntax that's only through Database Workbench or also with a linked server?

Comment: I have no experience with linked servers, but I would very much assume that  SQL Server simply sends the SQL statement to the "other" database and the execution of the statement is then done there. So you could only use SQL that is valid for Firebird when querying the linked server. I highly doubt SQL Server has a built-in translation from T-SQL to every other SQL dialect that is out there.

Comment: You will need to use standard SQL and you should be fine for most use cases (SQL Server supports most of standard SQL, including quoting objectnames with double quotes instead of square brackets).